# Convert number to time

Tags: sql, oracle

How to convert number 1.33408564814814 to time 32:01:05?

Comment: Is this post what you are looking for? [Converting a number into an HH:MM:SS time format - Oracle](http://www.forumtopics.com/busobj/viewtopic.php?t=21321)

Comment: Maybe one of the upvoters could explain the relation between a `float` and, well...what *is* 32:01:05? SS:MM:HH??

Comment: What i understand is : `1.33408564814814` is a duration in days and OP wants to convert this in hours:minutes:seconds

Comment: The float value is what you'd get if you subtracted one date from another, say 08:01:05 this morning from midnight yesterday. It's being converted to HH:MI:SS, but where the HH part isn't restricted to 24 (or 12) hours. It's really 1 day, 8 hours, 1 minute and 5 seconds, but the OP is choosing to shows days as multiples of 24 hours, giving 32 (1*24 + 8). (Hence the commented-out lines in @vc's answer, suppressing the more normal day display).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you actually want the result as a character string, you could use a function like this:

```
set serveroutput on format wrapped;

declare
function days_to_time (p_days number) return varchar2
is
  d number := p_days;
  h integer;
  m integer;
  s integer;
begin
  h := trunc(d*24);
  d := d - h/24;
  m := trunc(d*24*60);
  d := d - m/24/60;
  s := round(d*24*60*60);
  return(h||':'||to_char(m,'FM00')||':'||TO_CHAR(s,'FM00'));
end;
begin
  dbms_output.put_line(days_to_time(1.33408564814814));
end;
/

anonymous block completed
32:01:05
```

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT
-- EXTRACT(day FROM numtodsinterval(1.33408564814814 , 'DAY')) Days,
EXTRACT(day FROM numtodsinterval(1.33408564814814 , 'DAY')) * 24 + EXTRACT(hour FROM numtodsinterval(1.33408564814814 , 'DAY')) TotalHours,
-- EXTRACT(hour FROM numtodsinterval(1.33408564814814 , 'DAY')) Hours,
EXTRACT(minute FROM numtodsinterval(1.33408564814814 , 'DAY')) Minutes,
EXTRACT(second FROM numtodsinterval(1.33408564814814 , 'DAY')) Seconds
FROM dual;
```

Answer (score 2):

The original number is an interval expressed as a number of days.  The following is a bit ugly but might help show what's going on:

```
SELECT days,
       hours,
       minutes,
       seconds,
       TO_CHAR(days, 'FM9') || ' ' ||
         TO_CHAR(day_hours, 'FM09') || ':' ||
         TO_CHAR(minutes, 'FM09') || ':' ||
         TO_CHAR(seconds, 'FM09') AS interval_string,
       TO_DSINTERVAL(TO_CHAR(days, 'FM9') || ' ' ||
                       TO_CHAR(day_hours, 'FM09') || ':' ||
                       TO_CHAR(minutes, 'FM09') || ':' ||
                       TO_CHAR(seconds, 'FM09')) actual_interval
 FROM (SELECT float_val,
              days, hours, minutes,
              hours - (days * 24) AS day_hours,
              ROUND((((decimal_hours - hours) * 60) - trunc((decimal_hours - hours) * 60)) * 60) AS seconds
      FROM (SELECT float_val,
                   trunc(hours / 24) AS days,
                   decimal_hours,
                   hours,
                   (decimal_hours - hours) * 60 AS decimal_minutes,
                   trunc((decimal_hours - hours) * 60) AS minutes
              FROM (SELECT float_val,
                           float_val * 24 AS decimal_hours,
                           TRUNC(float_val* 24) AS hours
                      FROM (SELECT 1.33408564814814 AS float_val FROM dual))));
```

Share and enjoy.