# How do I convert a timestamp to hours?

Tags: oracle, timestamp

I am doing the following query in Oracle:

Field "NO" is a number, and field "DATETIME" is a timestamp.

```
select
    ARC.NO,
    MAX(ARC.DATETIME) - MIN(ARC.DATETIME) AS HORAS_TRABAJADAS
FROM archivo ARC
GROUP BY ARC.NO;
```

The result is:

```
NO 256  
DATETIME 1 8:8:41.0
```

I see that the "1" is shown in the left side and then some time.

I want to know if it is possible to show 16:17:22 (which is 8.8:41:0 X 2), because it is supposed to be 16:17:22.

Comment: If you can edit your question to include the `CREATE` statement for the `archivo` table and the `INSERT` statements for those rows you are selecting from it would be helpful.

Comment: The 1 is one day; are you sure you expect 16:17:22 rather than 32:08:41 (24 + 8 hours)? Where is the times-2 coming from?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28432281/266304) but depends on response to previous comment...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you subtract one timestamp from another [the result is an interval](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF00208). The value you can see, `1 8:8:41.0`, represent 1 day, 8 hours, 8 minutes and 41 seconds. It isn't clear why you think the result should be double that, but it would not be correct to interpret that value as `16:17:22`.

As a quick demo with two invented timestamps:

```
with archivo (no, datetime) as (
  select 256, timestamp '2015-08-14 11:37:16' from dual
  union all select 256, timestamp '2015-08-13 03:28:35' from dual
)
select ARC.NO, MIN(ARC.DATETIME) AS MIN_DATETIME, MAX(ARC.DATETIME) AS MAX_DATETIME,
  MAX(ARC.DATETIME)-MIN(ARC.DATETIME) AS HORAS_TRABAJADAS
from archivo ARC GROUP BY ARC.NO;

        NO MIN_DATETIME          MAX_DATETIME          HORAS_TRABAJADAS
---------- --------------------- --------------------- -----------------------------
       256 2015-08-13 03:28:35.0 2015-08-14 11:37:16.0 +000000001 08:08:41.000000000
```

If you want to display the interval in a different format then you will need to extract its components, e.g.:

```
select NO,
  EXTRACT(day FROM HORAS_TRABAJADAS) || ' days, '
    || EXTRACT(hour FROM HORAS_TRABAJADAS) || ' hours, '
    || EXTRACT(minute FROM HORAS_TRABAJADAS) || ' minutes and '
    || EXTRACT(second FROM HORAS_TRABAJADAS) || ' seconds'
    AS HORAS_TRABAJADAS
from (
  select ARC.NO, MAX(ARC.DATETIME)-MIN(ARC.DATETIME) AS HORAS_TRABAJADAS
  from archivo ARC GROUP BY ARC.NO
)

        NO HORAS_TRABAJADAS
---------- --------------------------------------------------
       256 1 day, 8 hours, 8 minutes and 41 seconds
```

I've used inline view to avoid repeating the max-min calculation but that's optional.

Or to add the number of days as multiples of 24 hours:

```
select NO,
  24 * EXTRACT(day FROM HORAS_TRABAJADAS) + EXTRACT(hour FROM HORAS_TRABAJADAS)
    || ':' || LPAD(EXTRACT(minute FROM HORAS_TRABAJADAS), 2, '0')
    || ':' || LPAD(EXTRACT(second FROM HORAS_TRABAJADAS), 2, '0')
    AS HORAS_TRABAJADAS
from (
  select ARC.NO, MAX(ARC.DATETIME)-MIN(ARC.DATETIME) AS HORAS_TRABAJADAS
  from archivo ARC GROUP BY ARC.NO
);

        NO HORAS_TRABAJADAS
---------- ----------------
       256 32:08:41
```

There isn't a simple `to_char()` equivalent for intervals though, unfortunately.