# Find the difference between two dates in hours and minutes

Tags: sql, oracle, date-difference

I am trying to come up with a way to calculate the difference between two dates in hours and minutes.

I have a table with two columns `Start Date` and `TimeStamp`:

```
Start Date              Timestamp
--------------------    --------------------
05/JAN/2016 05:30:00    01/JAN/2016 10:02:29
30/JAN/2016 06:10:00    18/JAN/2016 19:24:00
23/JAN/2016 06:10:00    08/JAN/2016 10:46:00
05/JAN/2016 05:30:00    30/DEC/2015 16:07:00
23/JAN/2016 06:10:00    08/JAN/2016 12:18:05
01/JAN/2016 14:10:00    16/DEC/2015 16:36:56
01/JAN/2016 14:10:00    16/DEC/2015 11:41:00
03/JAN/2016 05:15:00    02/JAN/2016 11:23:15
03/JAN/2016 05:15:00    02/JAN/2016 07:52:00
```

I use the query:

```
select ROUND(RM_LIVE.CRWGNDACTTIME.GNDACTSTARTRM_LIVE.TRANSACTIONLOG.TIMESTAMP,2)
                       AS "Difference"
  from Transaction;
```

The query result is:

```
0.002721428571428571428571428571428571428571
0.008178571428571428571428571428571428571429
0.0105785714285714285714285714285714285714
0.003971428571428571428571428571428571428571
```

Expected result:

```
133:23
 91:28
355:24
353:52
274:46
```

I got that expected result in Excel using this formula:

```
= MAX(T982+U982,W982+V982) - MIN(T982+U982,W982+V982)
```

How can I get the same result in Oracle SQL?

```
CASE
  WHEN trunc(24 * abs(RM_LIVE.TRANSACTIONLOG.TIMESTAMP
- RM_LIVE.CRWGNDACTTIME.GNDACTSTART))
  ||':'|| lpad(round(60 * mod(24 * abs(RM_LIVE.TRANSACTIONLOG.TIMESTAMP
- RM_LIVE.CRWGNDACTTIME.GNDACTSTART), 1)), 2, '0')  <= '11:00' THEN     'LESS'
ELSE 'MORE'
END AS "mORE/LESS",


386:29  1055    01-JAN-16   16-DEC-15   MORE
**102:41    1055    08-NOV-15   04-NOV-15   LESS**
381:33  1055    01-JAN-16   16-DEC-15   MORE
176:45  1055    20-NOV-15   12-NOV-15   MORE
**119:54    1055    08-NOV-15   03-NOV-15   LESS**
```

Comment: i checked but there is not wht i looking for there is only days not in hours

Comment: his asking result in 24 hours and im asking difference two dates in Hours so there two different thing

Comment: Why are they different? For your first row, `05/JAN/2016 05:30:00    01/JAN/2016 10:02:29`, the difference is 3 days, 19 hours, 27 minutes and 30 seconds; 3 days is 72 hours, so the total is 91 hours. The query on that linked question gives 91:27:30. For your fourth value it gives 133:22. You can just leave off the seconds part?

Comment: but i dont know how to make Query ??

Comment: Thanks Done 
round(24*( to_date(RM_LIVE.CRWGNDACTTIME.GNDACTSTART,'dd/mon/yyyy HH24:MI:SS')-to_date(RM_LIVE.TRANSACTIONLOG.TIMESTAMP,'dd/mon/yyyy HH24:MI:SS')),2) AS "dIFFERENCE",

Comment: Well that gives you decimal fractions like 91.46 instead of 91:28, but if that's good enough that's fine. But if GNDACTSTART and TIMESTAMP are already dates you should *not* be calling TO_DATE() for them, you're doing implicit and unnecessary conversions which will break if your NLS settings change. Just `round(24*(RM_LIVE.CRWGNDACTTIME.GNDACTSTART - RM_LIVE.TRANSACTIONLOG.TIMESTAMP,),2)` ought to be enough.

Comment: i neeed 91:28 how can i do that?

Comment: one more thing I dont need negative output like if crwgndacttime is less then time stamp so output will come in negative but i need output come in positive like in excel i did
=MAX(T982+U982,W982+V982) - MIN(T982+U982,W982+V982)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've shown a couple of variations with explanations in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28435478/266304), but it seems to be doing slightly more than you want - you don't want to see the seconds - and doesn't allow more than 100 hours.

The simplest way to get the output you want is with:

```
trunc(24 * (RM_LIVE.CRWGNDACTTIME.GNDACTSTART
    - RM_LIVE.TRANSACTIONLOG.TIMESTAMP))
  ||':'|| lpad(round(60 * mod(24 * (RM_LIVE.CRWGNDACTTIME.GNDACTSTART
    - RM_LIVE.TRANSACTIONLOG.TIMESTAMP), 1)), 2, '0')
as difference
```

The first part gets the whole number of hours, which is similar to a method you added in a comment, but truncating instead of rounding to only get the whole hours. Then there's a colon separator. Then the minutes are calculated by getting the remainder from the hours calculation - via `mod()` - which is the fractional number of hours, and multiplying that by 60. The `lpad()` adds a leading zero to the number of minutes, but you coudl use `to_char()` instead.

If you have a mix of ranges where timestamp could be before or after the start time then you can use [the `abs()` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions009.htm) to always get a positive result.

```
trunc(24 * abs(RM_LIVE.CRWGNDACTTIME.GNDACTSTART
    - RM_LIVE.TRANSACTIONLOG.TIMESTAMP))
  ||':'|| lpad(round(60 * mod(24 * abs(RM_LIVE.CRWGNDACTTIME.GNDACTSTART
    - RM_LIVE.TRANSACTIONLOG.TIMESTAMP), 1)), 2, '0')
as difference
```

As a demo with your data mocked up in a single table:

```
create table your_table(id, start_time, timestamp) as
  select 1, to_date ('05/JAN/2016 05:30:00', 'DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), to_date('01/JAN/2016 10:02:29', 'DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from dual
  union all select 2, to_date ('30/JAN/2016 06:10:00', 'DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), to_date('18/JAN/2016 19:24:00', 'DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from dual
  union all select 3, to_date ('23/JAN/2016 06:10:00', 'DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), to_date('08/JAN/2016 10:46:00', 'DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from dual
  union all select 4, to_date ('05/JAN/2016 05:30:00', 'DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), to_date('30/DEC/2015 16:07:00', 'DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from dual
  union all select 5, to_date ('23/JAN/2016 06:10:00', 'DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), to_date('08/JAN/2016 12:18:05', 'DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from dual
  union all select 6, to_date ('01/JAN/2016 14:10:00', 'DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), to_date('16/DEC/2015 16:36:56', 'DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from dual
  union all select 7, to_date ('01/JAN/2016 14:10:00', 'DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), to_date('16/DEC/2015 11:41:00', 'DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from dual
  union all select 8, to_date ('03/JAN/2016 05:15:00', 'DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), to_date('02/JAN/2016 11:23:15', 'DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from dual
  union all select 9, to_date ('03/JAN/2016 05:15:00', 'DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), to_date('02/JAN/2016 07:52:00', 'DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from dual
  union all select 10, to_date ('16/JAN/2016 11:15:00', 'DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), to_date('16/JAN/2016 12:44:00', 'DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from dual
  union all select 11, to_date ('16/JAN/2016 11:15:00', 'DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), to_date('16/JAN/2016 12:50:00', 'DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from dual;
```

The equivalent query:

```
select start_time, timestamp, trunc(24 * abs(start_time - timestamp))
    ||':'|| lpad(round(60 * mod(24 * abs(start_time - timestamp), 1)), 2, '0')
    as difference
from your_table
order by id;

START_TIME          TIMESTAMP           DIFFERENCE
------------------- ------------------- ----------
2016-01-05 05:30:00 2016-01-01 10:02:29 91:28     
2016-01-30 06:10:00 2016-01-18 19:24:00 274:46    
2016-01-23 06:10:00 2016-01-08 10:46:00 355:24    
2016-01-05 05:30:00 2015-12-30 16:07:00 133:23    
2016-01-23 06:10:00 2016-01-08 12:18:05 353:52    
2016-01-01 14:10:00 2015-12-16 16:36:56 381:33    
2016-01-01 14:10:00 2015-12-16 11:41:00 386:29    
2016-01-03 05:15:00 2016-01-02 11:23:15 17:52     
2016-01-03 05:15:00 2016-01-02 07:52:00 21:23     
2016-01-16 11:15:00 2016-01-16 12:44:00 1:29      
2016-01-16 11:15:00 2016-01-16 12:50:00 1:35
```

---

You can't easily compare the string value you want - and it has to be a string with a value like `91:28` - with anything else because string comparison of numbers doesn't work well. As you've see, comparing '119:54' with '11:00' is effectively comparing the third character of each string since the first two are the same, so `9` with `:`.

It would be simpler to leave it as a decimal fraction for comparison:

```
CASE
  WHEN round(24 * abs(RM_LIVE.TRANSACTIONLOG.TIMESTAMP
    - RM_LIVE.CRWGNDACTTIME.GNDACTSTART), 2) <= 11 THEN 'LESS"
ELSE 'MORE'
END AS "mORE/LESS",
```

For the 91:28 example, that will compare the decimal fraction version 91.46 instead; and for 119:54 will compare 119.9, which is more than 11; 102:41 will be compared as 102.68, which is also more than 11.

Or you could simplify it slightly by dividing the fixed value by 24 (hours in a day) instead of multiplying the time difference:

```
CASE
  WHEN abs(RM_LIVE.TRANSACTIONLOG.TIMESTAMP
    - RM_LIVE.CRWGNDACTTIME.GNDACTSTART) <= 11/24 THEN 'LESS"
ELSE 'MORE'
END AS "mORE/LESS",
```

Comment: in most of recoders im geeting this
-1:-2
-1:-3
if dates are like this
16/JAN/2016 11:15:00 16/JAN/2016 12:44:00
16/JAN/2016 11:15:00 16/JAN/2016 12:50:00

Comment: One more thing the DIFFERENCE result coming as a text how can i convert in Number or time

Comment: @CricBuzz - it can't be a number if you want it as 91:28 etc., you'd need the decimal version you had earlier, 91.46. Or split it as two numeric values, one for hours and one for minutes. And Oracle doesn't have a separate time data type; closest is interval but that won't allow hours > 23, and neither will anything else without converting that back to 3 days 19 hours. Your client or application will have to interpret the string. If this isn't just for display then not sure what you will do with it.

Comment: can we do tht 
if <=11:00 then less else more I tried but most of recods which more thn 112:00 give me less its should b more ? i post result in Question

Comment: It isn't greater than 11 when compared as a string, which is what is happening. If you want to compare it then it's easier to leave it as a decimal fraction. Please don't put code in comments like that, particularly when you've already added it to the question. Although it isn't really relevant to the original question anyway...

Comment: @CricBuzz - I've added that to the answer. Your edit to the question doesn't really make sense though - it doesn't match up with the rest. (It should have been a new question really, but it's just about trivial enough to get away with today)